# adb restore pauses indefinitely when source phone has SD card and target phone has none

Tags: adb, restore

I ran an adb backup like:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -nosystem -f /tmp/android-backup.ab
```

The backup progress screen stopped showing any progress, as did my `adb logcat | grep BackupManager`. A few minutes later, I ran an unfiltered `logcat` and found:

```
10-27 13:57:59.716  1546 30369 D BackupManagerService: Invoking agent to restore file 1/Download/some.pdf
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  : Binder call failed.
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  :      at com.android.sharedstoragebackup.SharedStorageAgent.onRestoreFile(SharedStorageAgent.java:80)
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  :      at android.app.backup.BackupAgent$BackupServiceBinder.doRestoreFile(BackupAgent.java:1112)
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  :      at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:179)
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 W Binder  :      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
10-27 13:57:59.733 16987 16998 D SharedStorageAgent: Shared restore: [ shared : 1/Download/some.pdf]
10-27 13:57:59.734  1546  8971 V BackupManagerService: opComplete: f86aebb result=0
```

How can I change my approach so that the restore will work the next time?

Comment: On the PC you can decrypt and extract the adb backup file, remove the sd-card files, repack everything and then apply/install it. Use [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor).

Comment: please note that `/sdcard` is unrelated to MicroSD Card

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that `some.pdf` can be found in the Downloads/ of the SD card of the source phone when connecting over MTP. I believe the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` traceback is a very unclear way of saying that there is no SD card on the target phone, where `adb restore` is trying to push the file.

I want to save the shared files, but not the ones in the SD card. I don't see any flags in `adb shell bu help` to do that.

So it looks like the best solution is to remove the SD card from the source phone, if the target phone does not have an SD card installed.